# Sorting by the last and first digit of numbers in an array (c++)

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I need to sort an array of numbers by looking first to their last digit first (and also comparing if another number in the array has the same last digit) and first digit second from minimum to maximum like bubble sort but with a twist.

For example: ()
array = {22,32,76,45,95,31,10,28,79,21}
return should be:
{10,21,31,22,32,45,95,76,28,79}
I've tried using this method down below but it gives numbers at random or sometimes to some extend correct.
Any help will be appreciated.

I did try this block of code:

```
#include <iostream>

bool checkNumber(int a,int b){
    // digits of A:
    int lastDigitA = a % 10; 
    int firstDigitA = (a - lastDigitA) / 10;
    // digits of B:
    int lastDigitB = b % 10;
    int firstDigitB = (b - lastDigitB) / 10;
    // checkif big or small:
    if(lastDigitA == lastDigitB){
        if(firstDigitA == firstDigitB){
            return true;
        }
        else if(firstDigitA < firstDigitB){
            return true;
        }
        else if(firstDigitA > firstDigitB){
            return false;
        }
    }
    else if(lastDigitA < lastDigitB){
        return true;
    }
    else if(lastDigitA > lastDigitB){
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    const int N = 10;
    int A[N] = {10,14,45,22,36,98,78,64,44,39};
    
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int temp = A[i];
        for (int j = N-1; j > i+1; j--) {
            if(checkNumber(A[i],A[j+1])){
                int min = A[j];
                A[j] = temp;
                A[i] = min;
            }
        }
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        std::cout << A[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What i got:

{39, 36, 14, 64, 45, 98, 14, 14, 14, 22}

what i was expecting:

{10, 22, 14, 44, 64, 45, 36, 78, 98, 39}

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run this code, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for and if you don't know how to use it, this is a good opportunity to learn running your program one line at a time in a debugger, monitoring all variables and their values as they change and analysing your program's logic and execution. It should be possible for you to use your debugger to find all simple problems in this and all future programs you write, all by yourself. Do you know how to use a debugger? Knowing how to effectively use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer.

Comment: Thank you for the criticism. I'm a student atm and learning c++ by myself. I'll dive deeper into debugging and learn from my mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example shows how code can cleanup if you use tested standard libary containers and algorithms.

Use std::vector for variable input length arrays.
For sorting use std::sort with a custom compare function.
And you will end up with code with a lot less (potentially buggy) index managment.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>


bool checkNumber(int lhs, int rhs)
{
    while ((lhs > 0) || (rhs > 0))
    {
        int l = lhs % 10;
        int r = rhs % 10;

        if (l != r) return l < r;

        lhs /= 10;
        rhs /= 10;
    }

    return false;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> values{ 22,32,76,45,95,31,10,28,79,21 };

    std::sort(values.begin(), values.end(), checkNumber);

    for (const int value : values)
    {
        std::cout << value << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this it solved my problem. I'll dive deeper into this code and learn from it.

Comment: Upvoted for not using a lambda.

Comment: @PeteBecker Consious choice (I usually do use lambdas in my own code). But I did want OP to recognize his own code (and to be honest it is quite readable like this)

Comment: @duirel Ask questions if you have them. The checkNumber is not perfect yet, will not work correctly if you have numbers of different length. (Your text did not specify what would need to happen then).